# Making a new line with single quotes?

Tags: php, newline, quotes, double-quotes, single-quotes

Can I do a line break like this `'\n'`?

Or do I must use double quotes - `"\n"`?

Comment: Why do you want it with single quotes?

Comment: because I use single quote to echo HTML like this `'<ul class="pagination">'` so I thought I could use single quote for `\n`.

Comment: Why don't you test such a simple thing??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use double quotes.  Otherwise, PHP will literally output `\n`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 4):

just add

```
.PHP_EOL;
```

to the end of your line using single quotes and you will have a new line

Answer (score 3):

To output a newline (or any other control character for that matter) you must always use double quotes.

An alternative to not use double quotes is [`chr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) with the respective [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/) as an argument:

```
echo chr(10); // same as echo "\n";
```

Comment: You can also (and it's better) use the constant PHP_EOL: `echo 'My'.PHP_EOL.'test;`

Answer (score 1):

No - `\n` in single quotes is '\n'.
Yes - you have to use double quotes.